# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '('

Tags: c, arduino

I'm just working on a RFID Sniffer on Arduino but something happened that it doesnt't work anymore.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

SoftwareSerial RDM630 = SoftwareSerial(2, 3); // RFID

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 16, 2);
SoftwareSerial ESP = SoftwareSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
pinMode(13, INPUT);
char rfid;
String dx;
bool connected = false;
String connbuff;
int lf = 10;
int cnt = 0;
bool lcdWAV = false;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  RDM630.begin(9600);
  ESP.begin(9600);
  ESP.listen();
}
```

The error says:

```
Documents/Arduino/rdm630_test/src/rdm630_test.ino:27:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before  '(' token 
lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
^
```

Now there is only the Setup routine and even this don't work. I only get the error...

Answer (score 2):

I forget that smth. like this:

```
pinMode(13, INPUT);
```

Need be placed in the

```
setup() {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't this basic C syntax? Statements have to be inside functions, only declarations can be outside functions.

Answer (score 2):

`pinMode(13, INPUT);` is a method call. Since a method can be called only from within a method so the line `pinMode(13, INPUT);` should be placed within a method body.